# How to upgrade the windows 10 on Lumia 535 without update advisor app

Tags: nokia-lumia-535, windows-10-upgrade

I have an old lumia 535 phone and could not upgrade the windows earlier. Now I want to upgrade the windows and unfortunately, Microsoft store for windows 8.1 is not functional and cannot install update advisor application. I would link to know that is there any alternative way to upgrade the windows on lumia 535 for example using windows computer?

Comment: Tool from Microsoft to upgrade the windows using pc: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56726

Comment: So did you solve the problem using the tool you linked?

Comment: yes. I was able to upgrade windows successfully on my cell phone.

Comment: Then consider posting the solution as an answer, ideally with more details than just a link, to help others who might have the same issue and find this post.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were following two ways to upgrade windows 10 on phones with windows 8.1:

1. Windows 10 Upgrade Advisor app
2. Over-the-cable Updater tool for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Mobile 10

However, after shutting-down of Windows 8.1 app store and unavailability of Upgrade Advisor app on phone, option 1 is no longer a solution. To upgrade the windows on phone using option, download the software from following link and follow the instruction:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56726

Comment: They may have closed the update server. Which would render this tool useless... Running this I get error (partial only) :
An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. Anyone by any chance still have "The update payload" that was downloaded during the upgrade process to the "Packages" subfolder of the tool install folder?